# Sass undefined mixin error - How to make main style file loads first

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, scss-mixins

I've installed an app using CRA and want to use SASS with it (I'm a new one in SASS installation and familiar with syntax)
Currently, I have this folders structure:

```
|── package.json
|
├── README.md
├── src
│   |
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── logo.svg
│   ├── React
│       ├── component
│       │   ├── Example
│       │       ├── Example.component.js
│       │       ├── Example.container.js
│       │       ├── Example.style.scss
|       |   
|       |
│       └── style
│           ├── abstract
│           │   ├── _abstract.scss
│           │   └── _media.scss
│           ├── _reset.scss
│           └── style.scss
|
├── webpack.config.js
└── yarn.lock
```

I want to declare some mixins inside the `_media.scss` file that will be used globally, for example, media queries.
Then I want to `@import 'media'` inside the `abstract` and `@import abstract` inside `style.scss` (I'm doing it to have all variables/mixins available globally)
`style.scss` is imported inside 'src/index.js' file.

Let's go to the `Example` component. There I have an `Example.style.scss` file, where I'm trying to use a mixin `<mixin_name>` I'm receiving an error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined mixin.
```

File `Example.style.scss` is imported inside Example.component.js (I prefer it since it is easier to import every file relatively close instead of importing each scss file in the `style.scss`).

I've read that to implement my needs I should install `sass-resources-loader`, so I've installed it and my `webpack.config.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "style-loader",
                },
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        importLoaders: 1,
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: "postcss-loader",
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                "style-loader",
                "css-loader",
                "postcss-loader",
                "sass-loader",
                {
                    loader: "sass-resources-loader",
                    options: {
                         resources: [
                            "./src/React/style/abstract/_media.scss",
                            "./src/React/style/style.scss",
                        ],
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
},
resolve: {
    extensions: [
        ".tsx",
        ".js",
        ".tsx",
        ".jsx",
        ".style.scss",
        ".scss",
        "...",
    ],
},
};
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@lagunovsky/redux-react-router": "^3.2.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.2.1",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^2.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "resolve-typescript-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-focus": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss-hover-media-feature": "^1.0.2",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^2.2.5",
    "stylelint": "^14.9.1"
  }
}
```

What should I do to configure my setup?

Comment: @Andril Antoniuk I am having the same issue on an Angular project.  Did you solve this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76068047/import-custom-mixin-fails-angular-15-bootstrap-5

Comment: @RooksStrife I have solved it for myself with my own npm module, but I think this 
isn't relevant for you since it`s craco related https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco-sass-loader

Answer (score 0):

A slight guess here but if you import style.scss into index.js it should make those mixins available to all components (assuming index.js is your entry file for the application)

`import './React/style/style.scss`

Comment: `style.scss` is imported inside 'src/index.js' file, and yes, this is my entry file